# How much cream can whip at once?

Tags: baking, dessert, cream

I am making a large quantity of a recipe that calls for whipped cream. I can use A KitchenAid mixer with the standard 4.5 quart bowl and whisk.  For efficiency sake, I’d like to whip as much as possible at one time, and would appreciate advice on how much Cream I should whip at one time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a 4.5l kitchen aid, the most cream I have ever whipped in it was 1l. The limitation is the wire whisk, you don't want so much that the level gets above the level at which the whisk can contact it, as then it won't whip effectively.

Too much also will get messy, getting all over the rotating parts.

Comment: Off the cuff, I’d agree. My bowl is a bit larger, I wouldn’t attempt to whip much more either.